# Auto scale RDS Database

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am trying to figure out how to Auto scale an RDS database from db.m6g.xlarge to db.m6g.8xlarge from 5AM est to 5 pm EST was wondering if anyone could help me out

I am trying to set up an auto scale process that will allow me to scale up the DB instance class at a set time and scale down the db instance at a set time

Answer (score 0):

AWS Auto-Scaling does not change the size of servers, it changes the number of servers in a server cluster.

If you want to change the size of your RDS server(s) on a schedule, then you will need to write some code, or an AWS CLI script, to automate that, and run it on a schedule.

You could accomplish this by creating an AWS Lambda function that runs twice a day, and issues an RDS [Modify DB Instance](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds/client/modify_db_instance.html) API call to modify the `DBInstanceClass` attribute of the instance.

Note that you can't modify the `DBInstanceClass` in place. A new RDS instance will be created, and the old one terminated, each time you do this.